# Filtrar consulta

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Como inserir um filtro na minha consulta o comando está em um repositório e quero inserir um filtro nele, pode ser por nome por exemplo.

Código:

```
public IList < T > Consultar() {
using(ISession session = FluentnHibernateHelper.OpenSession()) {
 return (from e in session.Query < T > () select e).ToList();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode inserir em outra lista os valores filtrados.

```
var suaListaAux = suaLista.Where(a => a.AtributoASerComparado == variavel ).ToList();
```

Sendo:

`suaLista` = Lista a ser filtrada
`suaListaAux` = Lista que receberá valor filtrado
`AtributoASerComparado` = Valor do retorno que deseja comparar
`variavel` = variavel que recebe o valor que será usado na compração

Isso filtrará sua lista para mostrar apenas os valores que possuem o que deseja.

Comment: Acabei fazendo de uma forma um pouco diferente, porém seguindo essa linha, muito obrigado pela ajuda meu querido. #PAZ

Comment: Que bom, posta como resolveu (Para se alguem tiver a mesma duvida) e se possível positiva se funcionou a minha ideia :).

Comment: Criei um metodo publico dentro da classe de repositório e inserir o seguinte codigo.
  using (ISession session = FluentnHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                var arquivo = session.QueryOver<Arquivo>()
                .Where(a => a.Primario == true);
                return arquivo.List<Arquivo>();


            }

Comment: Nice! parece que funciona

Comment: Sim sim, na verdade eu tenho pouca experiencia com C# trabalhando, to vendo coisas novas, como parametrização e hybernate.